# how to get the most commented set of records?

Tags: python, django

please help make a request by means of ORM.

is a model for comments on the video:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        verbose_name=u"Пользователь", 
        blank=True, 
        null=True,
    )   
    user_no_auth = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=u'Пользователь не авторизованный',
        max_length=100,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )       
    comment = HTMLField(
        verbose_name=u'Комментарий',
        max_length=50000, 
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )   
    video_id = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=u'Номер видео',
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )           
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=u'Дата создания',
        default=datetime.now(),
        auto_now=True,
    )
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=u'Дата последнего редактирования',
        default=datetime.now(),
        auto_now=True,
    )       
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=u'Активно',
        default=True,
    )
```

This model filled as [follows](http://hkar.ru/wDAh)

I need to get a set of identifiers video_id who have more total comments

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please do read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article on StackOverflow.  Also try to limit your code sample to the smallest code needed to demonstrate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your model definition is wrong. i dont see a ForeignKey in Comment Model from Video Model. `video_id`as IntegerField **does not** just belong there. this is how it should be:

Since you didnot post your Video Model, i just make up one:

```
class V_Video(models.Model): # 
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  # ....

class Comment(models.Model):
  video = models.ForeignKey(V_Video, related_name="video_comments")
  # .. other fields
```

the query to get e.g. 5 videos which have most comments is:

```
videos_with_most_comments = V_Video.objects.annotate(
                                               num_comments=Count('video_comments')
                                                   ).order_by('-num_comments')[:5]
```

here is the **[cheat sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)**